# How to add days to a date and pass the sum to an inputdate in c #?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I have a problem in a form within a `blazor` page.

I have two inputdate - in the first one I select a date and to that date I want to add 45 days. Once added those days stop that date to another inputdate within the form, but I don't know how to do this.

Previously I did it in `javascript` with `jquery` but at the moment I am working with `Blazor` and `c#` and it is complicating me a bit.

this is my inputdate:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Fecha de Cotización</label>
<InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@cotizacion.FechaCotizacion"></InputDate>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => cotizacion.FechaCotizacion)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>Fecha de Vencimiento</label>
<InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@cotizacion.FechaVencimiento"></InputDate>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => cotizacion.FechaVencimiento)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
```

I know you can do something like this but I really don't know where to start:

```
nuevaFecha = nuevaFecha.AddDays(45);
```

Comment: If you have a form textboxes and most controls contain strings.  So you cannot add 45 days to a string.  You can only add 45 days to a DateTime object.

Comment: yes i know it would be something like this: @{
    var fechaActual=DateTime.Now;
    var nuevaFecha = fechaActual.AddDays(45);
}

Comment: but that's why I don't know how to do what I need

Comment: You need to use DateTime.Parse(string) and then add days to the DateTime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet contains two InputDate components. When you select a date in the first one, the date in the second one changed to the selected date in the first component plus 45 days.

```
    @page "/"

<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <InputDate placeholder="Arrival Date" @bind-Value="person.ArrivalDate"
               @oninput="AddDays" />
    <InputDate placeholder="Departure Date" @bind-Value="person.DepartureDate" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => person.ArrivalDate)" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => person.DepartureDate)" />


    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</EditForm>

@code {

    private Person person = new Person();
    EditContext EditContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(person);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async Task AddDays(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        person.DepartureDate = Convert.ToDateTime(args.Value).AddDays(45);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TODO: Actually do something with the valid data");
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to bind each date to it's own property, and then take advantage of the property accessors (get and set) to do the work for you. It should be pretty easy to set up:

```cs
<EditForm Model="this">
    <InputDate @bind-Value="CurrentDate" />
    <InputDate @bind-Value="FutureDate" />
</EditForm>

@code {

    private DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime CurrentDate {
        get { return _currentDate; }
        set {
            if(value != _currentDate)
            {
                _currentDate = value;
                FutureDate = value.AddDays(45);
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime FutureDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddDays(45);
}
```

The way this works is that the page will automatically load with today's date as the `_currentDate` field, which is backing the `CurrentDate` property, which binds to the first `<InputDate>` component's value. the `FutureDate` property is bound to the second `<InputDate>` component. The trick is that in the `CurrentDate` property, when you set that value it updates the backing field and *also* updates the `FutureDate` property at the same time. This means that when the app is running, if you change the date in the first component the second one will auto-update to a day 45 days ahead of the first one. However, this doesn't work the other way around in this example, so the second one can be set to any date you wish and as long as the first date isn't touched, the two dates will be independent.

You could then use this setup to handle loading logic as well. The values for `CurrentDate` and `FutureDate` are coded to load up as today's date and a date 45 days in the future on initial component buildup, but you could then set the date for `CurrentDate` from an outside data source or lifecycle method and the second date would update on it's own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your time and help this served me perfect